# Lock Escalation and Count Discrepancy in lock_acquired Extended Event

Tags: sql-server, locking, lock-escalation

I'm trying to understand why there is a discrepancy in lock count in `sys.dm_tran_locks` and `sqlserver.lock_acquired` extended event in certain cases. Here is my repro script, I'm using the `StackOverflow2013` database on SQL Server 2019 RTM, compat level 150.

```
/* Initial Setup */
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.HighQuestionScores', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.HighQuestionScores; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.HighQuestionScores 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DisplayName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Reputation BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Score BIGINT
)

INSERT dbo.HighQuestionScores  
        (Id, DisplayName, Reputation, Score)
SELECT u.Id, 
       u.DisplayName,
       u.Reputation, 
       NULL
FROM dbo.Users AS u;

CREATE INDEX ix_HighQuestionScores_Reputation ON dbo.HighQuestionScores  (Reputation);
```

Next I update the table statistics with a large fake row count

```
/* Chaotic Evil. */
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.HighQuestionScores WITH ROWCOUNT = 99999999999999;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

Then I open a transaction and update `Score` for Reputation, say `56`

```
BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE dbo.HighQuestionScores  
SET Score = 1
WHERE Reputation = 56 /* 8066 records */
AND 1 = (SELECT 1);
/* Source: https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/helpers-views-and-functions-i-use-in-presentations/ Thanks, Erik */
SELECT *
FROM dbo.WhatsUpLocks(@@SPID) AS wul 
WHERE wul.locked_object = N'HighQuestionScores'
ROLLBACK;
```

I get a bunch of page locks (despite having an index on Reputation). I'm guessing the bad estimates really did a number on the optimizer there.

[image: page_locks]

I also double checked using `sp_whoisactive` and it too returns the same information.

```
<Object name="HighQuestionScores" schema_name="dbo">
  <Locks>
    <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__HighQues__3214EC072EE1ADBA" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="6159" />
  </Locks>
</Object>
```

Meanwhile I also have an extended event running on `sqlserver.lock_acquired` separately. When I look at the grouped data I see **8066** page locks instead of initial **6159**

[image: extended_event_lock_count]

I definitely do not a see a lock escalation (verified using `sqlserver.lock_escalation` event), so I guess my question is why is the extended event showing a discrepancy with a higher number of lock count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XE is reporting a page lock being acquired each time a row is updated (one event for each of the 8066 rows affected by the update).  However, these rows are only stored on 6159 unique pages, which explains the discrepancy.

I don't have StackOverflow2013 on this machine, but get a similar experience with SO2010:

- 1368 rows updated (and that many XEvents fired)
- 958 page locks

You can see the same pages being locked repeatedly in the XE output if you sort by `resource_0`:

[image: screenshot of XE output in SSMS]

Using `DBCC PAGE`:

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604); -- needed for the next one to work
GO

DBCC PAGE (StackOverflow2010, 1, 180020, 3);
GO
```

I can see that page 180020 has 163 records on it (`m_slotCnt = 163`):

```
Page @0x000002C278C62000

m_pageId = (1:180020)               m_headerVersion = 1                 m_type = 1
m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                m_level = 0                         m_flagBits = 0x0
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 174   m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 256 
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 72057594049331200                                
Metadata: PartitionId = 72057594044350464                                Metadata: IndexId = 1
Metadata: ObjectId = 1525580473     m_prevPage = (1:180019)             m_nextPage = (1:180021)
pminlen = 24                        m_slotCnt = 163                     m_freeCnt = 31
m_freeData = 7835                   m_reservedCnt = 0                   m_lsn = (203:19986:617)
m_xactReserved = 0                  m_xdesId = (0:0)                    m_ghostRecCnt = 0
m_tornBits = 1894114769             DB Frag ID = 1
```

And that 3 of those match the update criteria (I pasted the output into notepad++ and searched for "Reputation = 56"):

[image: screenshot showing 3 mathes]

Here's the first match, as an example:

```
Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS
Record Size = 39                    
Memory Dump @0x000000EDB2B7821D

0000000000000000:   30001800 86540000 38000000 00000000 6041c2e4  0...T..8.......`AÂä
0000000000000014:   c3020000 04000801 00270045 00720069 006300    Ã........'.E.r.i.c.

Slot 9 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 4 Length (physical) 4

Id = 21638                          

Slot 9 Column 2 Offset 0x1f Length 8 Length (physical) 8

DisplayName = Eric                  

Slot 9 Column 3 Offset 0x8 Length 8 Length (physical) 8

Reputation = 56                     

Slot 9 Column 4 Offset 0x0 Length 0 Length (physical) 0

Score = [NULL]                      

Slot 9 Offset 0x0 Length 0 Length (physical) 0

KeyHashValue = (e1caffa60313)       
Slot 10 Offset 0x244 Length 43
```

I believe this behavior is due to the pipelined nature of execution plans, and the way this specific XE is implemented.